# Google Cloud Build : Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts : google_compute_known_hosts

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

From a Cloud Build Trigger, I am connecting to a Compute Engine instance using the *gcloud compute ssh* command.

But I receive this warning:

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts).
```

I tried to create the folder, it has rights drwxrwxr-x but still, I receive this warning.

Do you have any idea of the reason why I can't add the host to the list of known hosts?

Thank you in advance!

for information, here are my steps:

```
mkdir -p /builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts && \ 
chmod g+w /builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts && \
gcloud compute ssh instance_name --ssh-key-file=~/root/.ssh/id_rsa --zone=zone --command='/bin/sh /opt/pull.sh'
```

Comment: `google_compute_known_hosts` is a file and not a directory. You are creating a directory in this step `mkdir -p /builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`.

Comment: How silly... I was sure it would be a list of files...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @John Hanley , I could change my YAML file:

I created a file instead of a folder:

```
mkdir -p /builder/home/.ssh/ && \ 
touch /builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts && \
```