# Google Cloud Platform Cloud Build - permission denied (publickey) when using gcloud CLI to access Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I Have a [Cube.js](https://cube.dev/) application running on a GCP Compute Engine VM, through docker compose, and I need to setup automatic continuous deployment.

The idea here is to always run a specific script on the VM through SSH when needed, which stops the docker container, pulls the new code from the remote repository, and re-runs docker compose.

So far, I have managed to setup a Cloud Build trigger when a commit is made to a specific branch, and the script is also working fine (I have tested it by logging into the machine manually).

The issue is on my `cloudbuild.yaml` file: when running the `gcloud compute ssh` command, I always seem to get the error `root@vm-ip: Permission denied (publickey)`, which disallows me to ssh into the VM to run the script I have to run.

I have tried multiple solutions for this, and none of them seem to work to get past this. Some examples I have tried:

Not using a predefined SSH key:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    id: Update dev cube
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud compute ssh <vm-id> --zone=<vm-zone> --strict-host-key-checking=no --command='/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh'
```

Using a predefined SSH key (which I did add to the VM SSH Keys metadata):

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    id: Update dev cube
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        echo "$$CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY" > /workspace/key
        echo "$$CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY_PUB" > /workspace/key.pub
        chmod 600 /workspace/key
        chmod 600 /workspace/key.pub
        gcloud compute ssh <vm-id> --ssh-key-file=/workspace/key --zone=<vm-zone> --command='/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh'
    secretEnv:
      - 'CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY'
      - 'CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY_PUB'
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/<project-id>/secrets/<key-id>/versions/latest
      env: 'CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY'
    - versionName: projects/<project-id>/secrets/<pub-key-id>/versions/latest
      env: 'CLOUD_BUILD_SSH_KEY_PUB'
```

Here are some sample errors I have gotten over trying this again and again:

```
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.XXXXXXXXXXXXX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
root@<vm-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts).
root@<vm-id>: Permission denied (publickey).

Recommendation: To check for possible causes of SSH connectivity issues and get
recommendations, rerun the ssh command with the --troubleshoot option.

gcloud compute ssh <vm-id> --project=<project-id> --zone=<zone> --ssh-key-file=/workspace/key --troubleshoot

Or, to investigate an IAP tunneling issue:

gcloud compute ssh <vm-id> --project=<project-id> --zone=<zone> --ssh-key-file=/workspace/key --troubleshoot --tunnel-through-iap

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 255
```

What am I missing here? The problem really always seems to be the connection to the VM through SSH (which works fine outside of Cloud Build).

Or am I going about this whole CD thing all wrong? Any other flow suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The SSH server logs will answer your question about why the keypair is not working. Edit your post and include relevant sections from the SSH server logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this suggestion from John Hanley and Berangar from a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166677/google-cloud-build-failed-to-add-the-host-to-the-list-of-known-hosts-google) that including a command in their yaml file to create a file seems to resolve the concern. Berangar included this to their yaml file:

```
mkdir -p /builder/home/.ssh/ && \ 
touch /builder/home/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts && \
```